# There is a way to generate some kind of a hash of a text to comparison?

Tags: string, algorithm, comparison

I don't know if what I want is possible, but is this:

Suppose I have a few phrases,  I want to generate some kind of fewer string of that phrase that can represent the text. I will apply this for a lot of texts. After that, I compare the resulting strings to see how much different are one text from the other.

I don't need to know where are the differences or retrieve the original string, I only need this to compare strings.

There is something like this? I'm complicating the solution?

Comment: If you want a measure of **how much** difference there is between two strings, a hash is not what you want.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, a hash is not, but something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such technique and is called fuzzy hashing. Take a look at [ssdeep](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/). You also might be interested in the paper `Identifying almost identical files using context triggered piecewise hashing`.